# ¿Como dirigir una ruta a un modulo, desde un paquete en una ubicación diferente a la raiz de Python?

Tags: python, packages

Estoy creando un paquete distribuible, sin embargo el archivo **setup.py** lo tengo en una ubicación diferente a la raiz de Python y no se como direccionarlo. La dirección actual de mi **setup.py** es (*C:/Users/User/Desktop/Carpeta/Curso/paquetedistribuible/setup.py*) y la dirección de mi modulo es (*C:/Users/User/Desktop/Carpeta/Curso/paquetes/calculos_generales.py*). Actualemente intente lo siguiente:

```
from setuptools import setup
import sys

setup(

    name="paquetecalculos",
    version="1.0",
    description="Paquete para calculos matematicos basicos",
    author="Andres",
    author_email="andres.pena.arq@gmail.com",
    url="www.fadfasdfa.com",
    packages=[sys.path.insert(0, "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Carpeta/Curso/paquetes"),"calculos_generales"]

    )
```

Sin embargo no logro crear la ruta, agradeceria si me pudieran ayudar.

Comment: Creo que vas a tener que cambiar la jerarquía de tu paquete... Usualmente el `setup.py` se pone en la ruta raíz del proyecto (antes de todos los módulos)... En tu caso sería la carpeta `Curso`, pero a lo mejor puedes crear otra que incluya a las otras que vas a utilizar

Comment: Si, me toco reubicar el programa en una misma carpeta junto con el `setup.py` y funciono, tambien simplifique el codigo. Gracias